# Python Formula Structure

Tags: python

I have a formula that I am trying to convert a formula from Excel VBA to Python.  The formula in Excel VBA has the following form:

```
result = myAverage ^ 0.5 * 252 ^ 0.5
```

I am taking a 21 day average of a time-series, square rooting, multiplying by 262 and then square rooting again.  An example where 
myAverage = 0.257155781 would look like:

```
result = 0.000262417 ^ 0.5 * 252 ^ 0.5
```

where the desired result should equal `0.257155781`

I have tried several different ways in python of calculating result and I keep getting a value that is in consistent with the VBA version. I have tried the following:

The iterations of the formula I have tried are as follows - where myAverage is a dataframe df[name+"_Result21"]

```
df[name+"_Result21"] = df[name+"_RAWHISTVOLMATRIX"].rolling(window=21).mean()
df[name+"_Result21"] = np.sqrt(((np.sqrt(df[name+"_Result21"]))*252))
```

and

```
df[name+"_Result21"] = df[name+"_RAWHISTVOLMATRIX"].rolling(window=21).mean()
df[name+"_Result21"] = np.sqrt(np.sqrt(df[name+"_Result21"])*252)
```

and

```
df[name+"_Result21"] = df[name+"_RAWHISTVOLMATRIX"].rolling(window=21).mean()
df[name+"_Result21"] = np.sqrt(df[name+"_Result21"])
df[name+"_Result21"] = df[name+"_Result21"]*252
df[name+"_Result21"] = np.sqrt(df[name+"_Result21"])
```

If someone could offer how to correctly structure the formula it would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `result = (myAverage ** 0.5) * (252 ** 0.5)`

Comment: In VBA you're doing `(avg^0.5)*(252^0.5)` and in python you're doing `(252*(avg^0.5))^0.5`